# How to get internet connection latency/ping?

Tags: java, android, ping, latency, internet-connection

I need to get the current internet connection latency in ms. After doing a research in Stack Overflow, I found this code to get the latency:

```
            String host = "www.google.com";
            int timeout = 10000;
            long beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            boolean reachable =  InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout);
            long afterTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long latency = afterTime - beforeTime;
```

I also tried with `8.8.8.8` which is google DNS IP, and the result is the same.

The problem is that `latency` variable is very big in some devices, abnormal value, for example, sometimes 60, sometimes 400 ms in a Pixel XL, and always around 3000 ms in a slow device from 2014 with android 5.0. also in the simulator is always around 6000 ms, but I think that simulator doesn't give correct values.

In that device with Android 5.0 with around 3000 ms of latency returned by that code, when I open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it's super fast, and **if I try various online internet connection tests in the navigator of the device, the latency is 30 ms, so those 3000 ms of latency are false.** It's the same with the other devices.

How can latency be measured correctly in Android?

Comment: try multiple times and check the average

Comment: `isReachable` isn't really deterministic on what it actually does for specific devices.To get repeatable results, you should really do some specific network operation. You could utilize a socket for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45416203/2232127 . Regardless, you're usually constricted to use a server with some sort of controlled behaviour (e.g. easiest to use your own) otherwise you introduce all kinds of overhead which is unknown to you.

Comment: @JensV do you have a working piece of code of that? that non accepted solution is some kind of pseudocode sample without real class names or real use for example for that socket variable, etc..