# In SQL Server Profiler shows - Query Execution takes 1ms but in Spring App takes 30ms, where is the delay?

Tags: spring, azure-sql-database, spring-batch, hikaricp, azure-sql-server

I have a simple Table created in Azure SQL Database

```
CREATE TABLE DeleteMe(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [char](255) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [char](255) NOT NULL,
    [Age] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DOJ] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [Role] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
    
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [clusteredindexdeleteme] ON DeleteMe
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [LastName] ASC,
    [FirstName] ASC,
    [Age] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

In SQL Server Profiler shows - Query Execution takes less than a 1ms

[image]

but in Spring App takes 30ms

```
INFO : 01.05.2022:1754 (40.419) [[]main] HikariDataSource: springHikariCP - Starting...
INFO : 01.05.2022:1754 (41.941) [[]main] HikariDataSource: springHikariCP - Start completed.
Execution Started: 2022/01/05 17:54:41.948
INFO : 01.05.2022:1754 (41.950) [[]main] HikariDataSource: springHikariCP - Starting...
INFO : 01.05.2022:1754 (42.139) [[]main] HikariDataSource: springHikariCP - Start completed.
Select Query Execution Started: 2022/01/05 17:54:42.225
Select Query Execution Completed: 2022/01/05 17:54:42.251
```

**Java Application:**

```
public class JDBCSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...

        try {
            Connection conn = dataSource().getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs ;
            try {
                LocalDateTime executionStartTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                System.out.println("Select Query Execution Started: " + dtf.format(executionStartTime));
                
                rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ID from Delete Where ID = 50");

                executionEndTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                System.out.println("Select Query Execution Completed:  " + dtf.format(executionEndTime));
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
                return; // Exit if there was an error
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public static DataSource dataSource(){
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://....;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("...");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("...");
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Note:** When I execute the same application against the local server installed on the Dev laptop, it is taking only 6ms.

**Note:** I am executing this application from Azure Kubernetes.

Where is the delay? How do I fix this so that the Spring application will not take more than 2ms.

Comment: Local, its taking 6 seconds?? Why do you try spring data jpa?

Comment: My bad it is 6ms

Comment: hmmm...  Okay...

Comment: Did you check latency? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Should it not be "Select ID From DeleteMe" not Delete. table name is wrong in select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We opened a case with Microsoft support and figured that there is an issue with coreDNS at AKS cluster and requested Microsoft Product group to increase the resources for coreDNS Pods.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have shared here I assume the delay is in network latency.

Dev Java App to Dev Server takes 6 seconds.

Azure Kubernetes App to Azure SQL Database takes 30 ms.
Which I think is reasonable if you include the network latency between app and server. I dont think you will get result in 2 ms. If you get, please let me know ;)

Try to check network latency in some ways like doing on `SELECT 1` query and calculate turnaround time.

interesting read:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/testing-client-latency-to-sql-azure/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/igorpag/azure-network-latency-sql-server-optimization
https://github.com/RicardoNiepel/azure-mysql-in-aks-sample
[There is a way to measure latency network in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416012/there-is-a-way-to-measure-latency-network-in-java)